# Powershell - How to ignore double rows while importing csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Is it possible to ignore rows which have the same name and surname while importing data from csv in PowerShell. Is it a way to ignore them and not to update them in AD?

I would prefer to get a message instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to add a new property to the imported csv where each user gets the combination of First and Surname. From then on it would be easy enough to skip the ones with the same Full names. (note i have taken LotPings example user in there to make sure it works as expected)

```
$csv = 'Name,Surname,ID
Stephen,Owen,1234
Lindey,Owen,2345
Stephen,Owen,3456
Pippin,Owen,4567
John,Elway,5678
Lindey,Elway,9876
John,Elway,5555'

$users = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
# add a column with the first and lastnames combined
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FullName' -Value ("{0} {1}" -f $user.Name, $user.Surname)
}

# now create an array with all users except those that have the same 'FullName'
$noDupes = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    If ($user.FullName -in $noDupes.FullName){
        Write-Warning "Skipping user $($user.FullName), ID $($user.ID), already processed"
        continue
    }
    "importing $($user.Name) $($User.SurName)"
    $noDupes += ($user)
}

$noDupes
```

Will yield:

```
importing Stephen Owen
importing Lindey Owen
WARNING: Skipping user Stephen Owen, ID 3456, already processed
importing Pippin Owen
importing John Elway
importing Lindey Elway
WARNING: Skipping user John Elway, ID 5555, already processed

Name    Surname ID   FullName    
----    ------- --   --------    
Stephen Owen    1234 Stephen Owen
Lindey  Owen    2345 Lindey Owen 
Pippin  Owen    4567 Pippin Owen 
John    Elway   5678 John Elway  
Lindey  Elway   9876 Lindey Elway
```

**Edit**

If you want to skip all users that have duplicates (not just the duplicates), you can use something like this:

```
$csv = 'Name,Surname,ID
Stephen,Owen,1234
Lindey,Owen,2345
Stephen,Owen,3456
Pippin,Owen,4567
John,Elway,5678
Lindey,Elway,9876
John,Elway,5555'

$users = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
# add a column with the first and lastnames combined
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FullName' -Value ("{0} {1}" -f $user.Name, $user.Surname)
}

# find all duplicate objects using the 'FullName'
$names = @()
$dupes = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    If (-not ($user.FullName -in $names)) {
        $names += ($user.FullName)
    }
    else {
        $dupes += $user.FullName
        Write-Warning "Duplicate user skipped: $($user.FullName)"
    }
}

$users = ($users | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notin $dupes })

$users
```

will yield:

```
Name   Surname ID   FullName    
----   ------- --   --------    
Lindey Owen    2345 Lindey Owen 
Pippin Owen    4567 Pippin Owen 
Lindey Elway   9876 Lindey Elway
```

Comment: And if i want to ignore double and oryginal entries?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added new code below to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely do-able!

First, let's assume you have a starting list of users like this

```
$csv = 'Name,Surname,ID
Stephen,Owen,1234
Lindey,Owen,2345
Stephen,Owen,3456
Pippin,Owen,4567
John,Elway,5678'

$users = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

In order to know if we processed a user already, we'll need a way of tracking each user as we process them, so we'll add each user to an ArrayList when we process them, like so.

```
$processed = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($user in $users){
   #Do your processing here
    $null = $processed.Add($user)
}
```

But we still need some logic to check and see if we have worked on a particular user before.  We can do that by checking to see if `$processed` contains a Name and SurName which match the `$user` we're working on at the moment.

```
ForEach ($record in $processed){
    if ($record.Name -eq $User.Name){
        If ($record.SurName -eq $User.SurName){
            Write-Warning "Skipping user $($user.Name) $($user.SurName), ID $($user.ID), already processed"
            continue #This Keyword skips this item and continues to the next in the list
        }
    }
}
```

Put it all together and you have this.

#### Finished Example

```
$users = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv 
$processed = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($user in $users){    
    ForEach ($record in $processed){
        if ($record.Name -eq $User.Name){
            If ($record.SurName -eq $User.SurName){
                Write-Warning "Skipping user $($user.Name) $($user.SurName), ID $($user.ID), already processed"
                continue
            }
        }
    }
    "importing $($user.Name) $($User.SurName)"
    $null = $processed.Add($user)
}
```

Which will output like the following (note that I have *two* entries for 'Stephen Owen' in the list)

```
importing Stephen Owen
importing Lindey Owen
WARNING: Skipping user Stephen Owen, ID 3456, already processed
importing Pippin Owen
importing John Elway
```

Comment: Add  `Lindey,Elway,9876` to your $csv and see what happens. You can't check indepently for name and surname.

Comment: Should i use this method ? $csv =  get-content c:\scripts\computers.csv | select -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "Name","Surname","ID"

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski No, as your title says, `$Users = Import-Csv 'X:\path\users.csv'`

Comment: So at the end of this loop I should just set-aduser with -Replace $processed parameter. Sorry to ask i am still trying to figure out PowerShell :)

Comment: Great point, @LotPings, I've updated my example to address this.

Comment: And if i want to ignore double and oryginal entries. How to remove this strings in arrays ? I believe i have to use Remove("$record") right?

Comment: This logic will just skip duplicates.  Only the first unique user with a given first and last name combination will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use Sort -Unique:

```
$users | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = "FullName"; Expression = { $_.Name + $_.Surname }}, Name, Surname, ID | Sort-Object FullName -Unique
```

though that doesn't let you know that users have been dropped.